# How to set the current day color in FullCalendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullcalendar

I would like to change the color of the current day but only when the calendar is in the day agenda view. My users say they're having a hard time seeing the lines or something. I looked through the documentation as well as the css/js and didn't find a quick way of doing it. Is this even possible without major code changes?

Comment: He is probably referring to jQuery UI's "fullcalendar" widget.

Answer (score 19):

I honestly don't really know what you're talking about, but the [jQuery UI fullcalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) widget uses the CSS class `.fc-today` to style the current day. If your changes aren't visible, try to use `!important` — it might be that one of the many other classes overrides your styles elsewhere.

Comment: The current day is yellow whereas all the other days are white. My users are having a hard time seeing the lines on the day agenda view for the current day because it is yellow. Sorry I should have been more specific and I believe that will fix my issue. I can change the css property for .fc-today with jquery while on the daily agenda view for the current day and back when not on the current day.

Thanks!

Comment: If only want to use css then do as follows:

in version 3.9.0 : 

`.fc-agendaDay-view .fc-today {
    background: white !important;
}
`

Comment: Good answers. But is there also an option in FullCalender to enable/disbale the current day indicator? Reason is, I use the calender in different types and want once to show the current day color but not on the other view.

Answer (score 19):

you can use following code

```
.fc-day-today {
    background: #FFF !important;
    border: none !important;
  
}
```

Answer (score 7):

**Full Calendar >= 5**

In fullcalendar >= 5, they changed the class name to `.fc-day-today`. However, you'll need to increase the specificity of that selector to override the styles OR use `!important` on the attribute you're overriding if it doesn't apply without it.

Note - I have NOT looked if the API supports something more native. If it does, probably a better long term solution.

Comment: "I have NOT looked if the API supports something more native. If it does, probably a better long term solution" It doesn't matter. FullCalendar is famous for changing completely the API in each new version.

Answer (score 6):

If you aren't using a theme, this worked for me using FullCalendar 2.3.1

```
.fc-unthemed .fc-today {
  background: ....;
}
```

Comment: Works great on version `2.9.0`

Comment: .fc-bg .fc-state-highlight{
  background-color:#009688 !important;
  
 } 
I used this to get the correct result. Fullcalender version 3.4.0

Answer (score 4):

I had multiple calendars so this worked:

```
#calendar .fc-today {
    background: #FFF !important;
}

#calendar-two .fc-today {
    background: #FFF !important;
}
```

Using `#calendar-favorite .fc-unthemed .fc-today { ... }` did not work, so remember to remove the `.fc-unthemed` part.

Also check out the jquery way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17930817/1066234 using `dayRender`

Answer (score 2):

This works for Vue Component of FullCalendar v5!

```
:deep( .fc-daygrid-day.fc-day-today ){
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

:deep( .fc-timegrid-col.fc-day-today) {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To change color/background of fullcalendar's current day in dayview, add the following CSS class and make sure it is loaded after all css styles.

```
  .fc-view-basicDay .fc-today {
     color:....;
     background:....;
  }
```

Comment: in version 3.9.0 use: 

`.fc-agendaDay-view .fc-today {
    background: white !important;
}
`

Answer (score 1):

for me it was `.ui-state-highlight.fc-today`

Answer (score 1):

Add this keyword  `!important`  to the end of the line just before the semicolon to override the default rules set for the css class `.fc-day-today`

**.js** file using jQuery

```
<script>

    $('.fc-day-today').addClass('cell-background');

</script>
```

***.css*** file

```
.cell-background {
    background-color:#D9FFE1 !important;
}
```

This worked for fullCalendar v5.8.0. You can apply the same concept for different.

Answer (score 0):

This work for me in `FullCalendar 3.6.1`

```css
#calendar-id .fc-widget-content:not(.fc-axis) {
       background: #FFF !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This work in today

```
.fc-timeGridDay-view {
  .fc-widget-content:not(.fc-axis) {
    .fc-today {
      background: red;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Good answers. But is there also an option in FullCalender to enable/disbale the current day indicator? Reason is, I use the calender in different types and want once to show the current day color but not on the other view.

Answer (score 0):

To highlight today in timeline view in v5 with SCSS

```
// make today highlight in red
.fc-day-today {
  border: 1px solid red !important;
  .fc-timeline-slot-frame {
      border-top: 1px solid red !important; 
  }
}
.fc-day-today + .fc-day-future {
  border-left: 1px solid red !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

that's work in v5.9.0

for the current day:

```
#calendar .fc-day-today{
background-color: #ff0000 !important;
font-size: 80%;
}
```

for month:

```
#calendar .fc-day{
background-color: #ff0000 !important;
font-size: 80%;
}
```

the id (#calender) is from

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was:

```css
.fc .fc-timegrid-col.fc-day-today {
  background-color: white;
}
```

But for yourself, it's better to follow the path of the console by turning on the display of the week

Answer (score 0):

For angular here is my solution:

```
:host ::ng-deep{
    .fc .fc-daygrid-day.fc-day-today {
        background: #f3533f;
     }
}
```

P.S.: No need to use `!important`

Answer (score 0):

In v5.11.3 you can use the following:

```css
:root {
    --fc-today-bg-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

the default fullcalendar css uses the css variable "--fc-today-bg-color" by default.