# Change the day background color in FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, fullcalendar

I'm using [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) in my asp.net application. I need to change the **day** background color.

**What i have tried so far :**

```
dayRender: function (date, cell) {

    var today = new Date();
    var end = new Date();
    end.setDate(today.getDate()+7);

    if (date.getDate() === today.getDate()) {
        cell.css("background-color", "red");
    }

    var start = new Date();
    start.setDate(today.getDate()+1);


    while(start <= end){

      //alert(start + "\n" + tomorrow);
        if(start.getDate() == date.getDate()){
            cell.css("background-color", "yellow");
        }

       var newDate = start.setDate(start.getDate() + 1);
       start = new Date(newDate);
    }        
}
```

This change background color of whole days. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z8Jfx/5/)

But my need is to change the background color of days, 7 days onward from current date.

**Example**

Today is 2013-July-29. I need to change the background color of below days.

```
2013-July-30
2013-July-31
2013-August-01
2013-August-02
2013-August-03
2013-August-04
2013-August-05
```

How can i do this ?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? Have you searched for a solution?

Comment: Are you using jqueryDatetimepicker

Comment: @putvande Yes.i tried with `dayRender` event in `FullCalendar`. still trying to achieve this since a few hours.

Comment: @AKA no. i'm using [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
dayRender: function (date, cell) {

    var today = new Date();
    var end = new Date();
    end.setDate(today.getDate()+7);

    if (date.getDate() === today.getDate()) {
        cell.css("background-color", "red");
    }

    if(date > today && date <= end) {
        cell.css("background-color", "yellow");
    }

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z8Jfx/7/

Comment: I have an another [qustion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942632/change-the-days-background-color-in-fullcalendar) about changing the days background color in FullCalendar. i'm thankfull to you if you can help me with it.

Comment: there is no function getDate() for date, it should be date.date() instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
dayRender : function(date, cell) {
                            var idx = null;
                            var today = new Date().toDateString();
                            var ddate = date.toDate().toDateString();

                            if (ddate == today) {
                                idx = cell.index() + 1;
                                cell.css("background-color", "azure");
                                $(
                                        ".fc-time-grid .fc-bg table tbody tr td:nth-child("
                                                + idx + ")").css(
                                        "background-color", "azure");

                            }

                        }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: @flob if you use agendaWeek and agendaDay views this one also changes the bakcground for them. Thanks to this: ".fc-time-grid .fc-bg table tbody tr td:nth-child(" + idx + ")" selector. Thats why it deserves a plus from me.