# Change the days background color in FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css, fullcalendar

I'm using [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) in my asp.net application. There are four `asp:Button`s in my application as below.

```
Weekends
Weekdays
Month
Year
```

When user click on `Weekends` button, i need to change the background color of `Weekend days` of current month.

When user click on `Weekdays` button, i need to change the background color of `Weekdays` of current month.

When user click on `Month` button, i need to change the background color of `all days` of current month.

When user click on `Year` button, i need to change the background color of `all days` of current year.

**What i have tried so far :**

Here is the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z8Jfx/10/) for change background color for weekends. this change background color of weekends including other months which are currently display on calendar. but i need to change only current months weekends background color only.

How can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there in your demo. You just need to filter out the days that are in other months - and luckily FullCalendar marks those days with the CSS class `fc-other-month`.

By changing your code slightly here's how you could do it for weekends:

```
$('#weekends').click(function() {

    $('.fc-day.fc-sat').not('.fc-other-month').css('backgroundColor','#bce8f1');
    $('.fc-day.fc-sun').not('.fc-other-month').css('backgroundColor','#bce8f1');

});
```

And an updated demo on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z8Jfx/22/

Comment: I have asked a new [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17984811/programmatically-selecting-a-period-of-time-in-fullcalendar). I'm thankful to you if you can help me with it.