# Programmatically selecting a period of time in Fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, fullcalendar

I'm using [Fullcalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar) in my `asp.net` application.

If we need to select a month, or a year in [Fullcalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar), there is a method as [`select`](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/selection/select_method/). We can pass `startDate` and `endDate` to that method and select that period.

I need to programmatically select `weekends` in a month. also need to select `week days` in a month.

How can i achieve this ?

**What i have tried so far :**

Here is the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z8Jfx/24/).

Comment: Do you mean you would like to select multiple non-consecutive days? I don't think that is possible with FullCalendar.

Comment: @user1332981 Yes. need to select multiple non-consecutive days.

Comment: What do you mean by wanting to select them? You could easily do something to highlight weekends, what is the specific scenario?

Comment: @tocallaghan not only highlighting. need to get dates from them. my scenario is select weekends from currently displaying month in fullcalendar with a button click. then i need to add events for selected weekends. assume i have same events on all weekends. so i need to select all weekends and add that events at once.

Comment: It sounds to me like more of a straight forward javascript/jquery requirement. You can get the current month (or day or week) from your calendar and then however you are creating your events can have the options you have in the demo (i.e. weekends, weekdays etc.). You can then use javascript/jquery to work out the required days

Answer (score 0):

So I've got your answer (I needed something very similar and stumbled across this when looking for help). We need to think outside of FullCalendar and the DOM for a minute. FullCalendar uses MomentJS, and this is about to come in handy (this wasn't included in your example, and you need it for the following). First, you need to create an array of either weekends or weekdays. I did so for the next 365 days (next full year).

**Example of Array of weekends using MomentJS:**

```
$('#weekends').click(function() {

    weekend_array = new Array();
    var cal = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getCalendar'); 
    var curr_moment = moment(cal);


    for(k=0; k<365; k++) // for the next 365 days (next year)
    {
        // if weekend
        if(curr_moment.day()==0 || curr_moment.day()==6) // 0 being Sunday, 6 being Saturday
        {
            weekend_array.push(curr_moment.format("YYYY-MM-DD")); // format to match the data-date attr
        }

        curr_moment= curr_moment.add(1, 'days');

    }

    console.log("Number of weekend days: " + weekend_array.length);
    console.log(weekend_array);

    var dates = weekend_array
    HighlightDates(dates);

    // help DOM restore checked dates on click
    $('#daymode').val('weekend');

});
```

So you have your weekend array for the next year. Now, we need to highlight the dates. Issue is that as soon as you click the arrows to view the next month, the selected dates are cleared (since we're working in the DOM) so i created the select dates in a function that can be called for weekdays, weekends or button click:

```
function HighlightDates(dates){
    $('.fc-day').each(function () {
            var thisdate = $(this).attr('data-date');
            var td = $(this).closest('td');

            if ($.inArray($(this).attr('data-date'), dates) !== -1) {
                td.addClass('fc-state-highlight');
            } else {
                td.removeClass('fc-state-highlight');
            }
        });
}
```

I hope this helps, working demo of everything. :D http://jsfiddle.net/z8Jfx/255/