# FullCalendar - select all Saturdays until end of year?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, fullcalendar

I'm having a really difficult time selecting dates with FullCalendar. Typically, you can select Saturdays by adding the highlight class:

```
$('.fc-sat').addClass('.fc-state-highlight');
```

but this will only chose the Saturdays for the month you are viewing.

```
 calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({});

          $('button').click(function(){
              // select all saturdays until end of year
              calendar.fullCalendar( 'select', start, [ end ] )
          });
```

I need the ability choose all Saturdays for the rest of the year on button click.
http://jsbin.com/xulixovape/1/

Comment: The days in other months aren't in the DOM at the time the button is clicked, so none of those cells are selected.  Try adding a [viewRender](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/viewRender/) method to your fullCalendar object, and if the button's been clicked, add the highlight class to the `.fc-sat` elements.

Comment: Answered the question here using MomentJS. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17984811/programmatically-selecting-a-period-of-time-in-fullcalendar/26632840#26632840