# How to change background color in one day of week in all FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm using [fullcalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/).

I would like to change background color all day of Friday.

for example:

```
2107-02-03
2107-02-10
2107-02-17
2107-02-24
...
```

how can I do?

Comment: see this thread:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17920017/change-the-day-background-color-in-fullcalendar

Answer (score 0):

If you have jQuery, you can do that with

```
$(".fc-fri").css("background-color", "red")
```