# Prevent default select of current day with fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, fullcalendar

I am using http://fullcalendar.io/. 
the calendar selects by default the current day of the week. How do you stop this ?
[image]

Comment: You read the documentation, and figure out how to set the [**default date**](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/current_date/defaultDate/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769707/current-day-color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could remove the background color using CSS:

```
.fc-today {
    background: none !important;
}
```